# Why should I conform Custom Protocol to NSObject?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, protocols, nsobject

Any object which assign to Custom protocol reference, is always be Confirm by NSObject Protocol directly or By superclasses. So Why should I do this?

Comment: Perhaps you could give an example?

Comment: who said you must to that?

Comment: Your title should say 'conform' not 'confirm'   You conform to a protocol, you don't confirm to it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might be trying to ask about using the `NSObject` protocol, since every class has `NSObject` as an ancestor.

The answer, then, is that it's *not* true that every object is derived from `NSObject`. Most are, but `NSProxy` is an example of one that's not. The methods in the `NSObject` *protocol* are what any instance of the `NSObject` *class* is expected to implement, so by implementing the `NSObject` *protocol*, `NSProxy` is able to provide the same behaviors that any class derived from `NSObject` (class) has.

For example, you can use methods like `-isEqual` and `-hash` with instances of `NSProxy`.

If you're creating a subclass of the `NSObject` class, there's no need to declare that your class implements the `NSObject` protocol because the `NSObject` class already does that for you.

Also, just as you can declare that a class adopts a protocol with:

```
@interface MyClass <SomeProtocol>
```

you can also declare that a protocol adopts another protocol:

```
@interface MyProtocol <SomeProtocol>
```

Since, as explained above, not *every* class is a subclass of `NSObject` (the class), having `MyProtocol` adopt `NSObject` (the protocol) guarantees that you can call `NSObject` methods. If you want to specify that a method takes any kind of object that adopts `YourProtocol`, you can do that by specifying the type as `id<YourProtocol>`. However, if `YourProtocol` isn't declared to adopt the `NSObject` protocol, you can't be certain that it's safe to call `NSObject` methods like `-isEqual`, and you can't even check that it's safe using `-respondsToSelector:` or `-isKindOfClass:` because those methods themselves are part of the `NSObject` protocol.

Comment: That was probably a better explanation like mine! But I took it at face value at how I saw OOP when I first dived in so went gentle.

Comment: Caleb , as you said not every class is derived from NSObject class. So if I adopt MyProtocol from NSObject, then I can use -isEqual, respondsToSelector:, etc. But In this case I will have to give body for these function what are declared in NSObject Protocol.

Comment: As long as your class descends from NSObject, you'll already have implementations for those methods. If it doesn't (which would be very unusual), then yes, you'll need to provide them.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know, whether I got you right.

If you meant that a custom protocol always confirms to the `NSObject` protocol, there is a pretty simply reason for it. It is a little bit weird:

If you type a reference to `id` the compiler accepts every message to that he has seen while compiling the translation unit ("class", "module", the file  you compile).

If you type an object reference to `id<protocol>`, the compiler only accepts messages that are declared inside the protocol. But this is never enough!

```
@protocol MyProtocol
@optional
- (void)doItOrNot;
@end
```

The only message you can send is `-doItOrNot`. So the compilation of such code will fail:

```
id<MyProtocol> ref = …;
if ([ref respondsToSelector:@selector(doItOrNot)]) // <- Error -respondsToSelector is not declared in the protocol.
…
```

By adding the `NSObject` protocol to your protocol you import some fundamental declarations. (Including MM for MRC.)

Comment: if i use - NSObject<MyProtocol> *delegate;
  Then it will not give compile error, respondsToSelector: is declared in NSObject class.

Comment: Of course, because the class `NSObject` implements the protocol `NSObject`. But this is dependency to a class that is not necessary for Objective-C. You do not need the class `NSObject`, you need the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Cocoa defines an NSObject protocol that mirrors the NSObject class and instance methods. By declaring that your custom protocol implements the NSObject protocol, you give the compiler a hint that all of the NSObject methods will be implemented by an instance that implements your custom protocol.

If you don't include the NSObject protocol, you'll get warnings when you try to call any of the NSObject methods for instance respondsToSelector: on the object.

Answer (score 0):

You don't *have* to. But the problem is that a lot of the core functionality of NSObject — indeed, all the core functionality necessary for NSObject to function as a base class — is declared in the NSObject protocol. (This strange architecture is so that both NSObject and NSProxy can be base classes: they both adopt the NSObject protocol.)

Now, if you declare an object's type as `id<MyDelegate>`, the only messages you can send that object are MyDelegate messages. That's fine, usually; but what if you want to send it, say, the `respondsToSelector:` message? That method is declared in the NSObject protocol, not in the MyDelegate protocol. So the compiler will stop you.

There are two solutions. Either declare the object's type as `NSObject<MyDelegate>`, or make MyDelegate adopt the NSObject protocol. Either way, the compiler is now satisfied, and you can send this object the `respondsToSelector:` message.